# List certain lines from a text file in python

Tags: python, text

The following is my list function:

```
def list():
    f = open("List.txt", 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    print("\n" + "Reading List...")
    print(lines)
    for line in lines:
        print(line)
    f.close()
    intro()
```

I want to print from the range 5 (so the 6th line), to the length of the lines. I have tried:

```
for line in range(5,len(lines)):
```

But that didn't work and only outputted the number of where the line is, not the line itself. I am fairly new to python and am unsure how I would go around doing this. Please give constructive criticism where possible. I am using a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by doing something like

```
for line in lines[5:]:
    print(line)
```